# Can light of different frequencies interfere with each other?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, superposition, non-linear-optics, linear-systems

In principle I'm aware of [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) and how it works. Nevertheless I'm not really able to answer the following: Will two light beams of different frequencies interfere with each other?
More precise: Assume a infrared emitter/sensor and a typical light source. By positioning them close to each other, will the latter be possible to have an impact on the infrared light?

Comment: In a vacuum no, in a transparent medium yes.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24244/

Comment: Thank you! So the result would be beat?